# custom sorting an array

Tags: java, python, arrays, sorting

An array of integers, arr, of size N is defined as {a , a , . . . , a }. It must take arr as a parameter, sort its elements in order of ascending frequency, and then print each element of the sorted array as a new line of output. If 2 or more elements have the same frequency, this subset of elements should be sorted in non-decreasing order.

```
Sample Input 0 53124 
Sample Output 0 1342
```

I am trying to solve this problem in Java and Python as my learning exercise and I got this working in Java but not sure how should I process it in Python.

```
public class CustomSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4 };
        customSort(arr);
    }

    static void customSort(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i : arr) {
            if(map.containsKey(i)) {
                map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(i, 1);
            }


            if (!numbers.contains(i)) {
                numbers.add(i);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(numbers);

        List<Integer> returning = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
        int count = 1;
        while(!returning.isEmpty()) {
            returning = print(returning, map, count);
            count++;
        }

    }

    static List<Integer> print(List<Integer> numbers, Map<Integer, Integer> map, int howManyItens) {
        List<Integer> returning = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer integer : numbers) {
            if(map.get(integer) == howManyItens) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= howManyItens; i++) {
                    System.out.println(integer);
                }
            } else {
                returning.add(integer);
            }
        }

        return returning;
    }
}
```

How should I do this in Python?

```
def customSort(arr):
    # what should I do here?
```

Comment: What part of the translation are you having trouble with?

Comment: Judging by the way you posed this question and your comment to the existing answer, you need to start with a basic Python tutorial, and SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: *# what should I do here?*, write some code probably. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
>>> li=[ 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4 ]
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda i: li.count(i))
[3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Or, you can do:

```
def c_sort(li):
    cnt={i:li.count(i) for i in set(li)}
    return sorted(li, key=lambda e: cnt[e])

>>> c_sort(li)
[3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

If you want a secondary sort key on the value of each element, form a tuple:

```
def c_sort(li):
    cnt={i:li.count(i) for i in set(li)}
    return sorted(li, key=lambda e: (cnt[e], e))

>>> c_sort(li)
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Can I use this in my customSort function as well instead of running it in interactive mode? I want to run as .py file.

Comment: Yes, you can use that in a .py file. Best of luck!